# ¿ Cómo agregar clase css a fila de una tabla usando DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy creando las filas de una tabla con la librería [DataTable Jquery](https://datatables.net/) y deseo agregar un estilo a una fila, las filas las genero de esta manera.

```
      // idTabla es una variable que la envió desde la vista **var idTabla = DataTable();**
            idTabla.row().clear();
            for (var i = 0; i < datos.length ; i++) {
                if (datos[i].estado == '1') {
                    var icon = "<i class='fa fa-check' id='loadState"+datos[i].id+"'></i>";
                }else{
                    var icon = "<i class='fa fa-ban' id='loadState"+datos[i].id+"'></i>";
                }
                //
                idTabla.row.add([
                                    datos[i].id,  
                                    datos[i].nombre,
                                    "<div class=' text-center col-md-12'><a href='#' id='editarObservacion"+datos[i].id+"' class=' ' onclick='activarDesActivarElect(\""+datos[i].id+"\", \"2\", \"loadState"+datos[i].id+"\", \""+id+"\", \""+datos[i].estado+"\")'> "+icon+" </a></div>"
                                ]);
            }
            idTabla.draw(true);
```

La intención de lo anterior es que cuando entre a el **else** agregue a toda la fila un color de letra diferente y de esta manera identificar los datos que entran con el **estado != 1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final logre agregar la clase de esta forma, dejo el código a continuación para que sirva a alguien que alguna vez tenga este mismo cuestionamiento

```
        idTabla.row().clear();
        for (var i = 0; i < datos.length ; i++) {
            if (datos[i].estado == '1') {
                icon = "<i class='fa fa-check' id='loadState"+datos[i].id+"'></i>";
            }else{
                icon = "<i class='fa fa-ban' id='loadState"+datos[i].id+"'></i>";
            }
            //
            idTabla.row.add([
                                datos[i].id,  
                                datos[i].nombre,
                                "<div class=' text-center col-md-12'><a href='#' id='editarObservacion"+datos[i].id+"' class=' ' onclick='activarDesActivarElect(\""+datos[i].id+"\", \"2\", \"loadState"+datos[i].id+"\", \""+id+"\", \""+datos[i].estado+"\")'> "+icon+" </a></div>"
                            ]);
            // agrego el idTabla.draw(true); dentro de el for
            idTabla.draw(true);
            if (datos[i].estado == '0') {
                // al parecer sorting_1 es una clase por defecto del plugin
                // allí encuentra un dato que contenga algo relacionado a la fila, en este caso es el id
                // utilizó parent() para asignarle una clase al "<td>" donde realiza lo que necesitaba
                $(".sorting_1:contains('" + datos[i].id + "')").parent().addClass('text-muted');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes definir una variable antes del for y darle (o no) un valor según el condicional, por último, obtener la fila actual y agregar una clase con jQuery:

```
idTabla.row().clear();
var rowClass;        
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length ; i++) {
    if (datos[i].estado == '1') {
        var icon = "<i class='fa fa-check' id='loadState"+datos[i].id+"'></i>";
        rowClass = false;
    } else {
        var icon = "<i class='fa fa-ban' id='loadState"+datos[i].id+"'></i>";
        rowClass = true;
    }
    var currentRow = idTabla.row.add([
        datos[i].id,  
        datos[i].nombre,
        "<div class=' " + rowClass + " text-center col-md-12'><a href='#' id='editarObservacion"+datos[i].id+"' class=' ' onclick='activarDesActivarElect(\""+datos[i].id+"\", \"2\", \"loadState"+datos[i].id+"\", \""+id+"\", \""+datos[i].estado+"\")'> "+icon+" </a></div>"
    ]).node();

   if (rowClass) {
       $(currentRow).addClass('mi-clase');
   } 
}
idTabla.draw(true);
```

Comment: La verdad es muy ingenioso, pero mira el problema es que en ese caso solo le colocaria el estilo a la última columna de esa tabla, la fila se empieza a "dibujar" por decirlo de algún modo, aquí `idTabla.row.add([` y los datos separados por **coma(,)** son los datos que van en cada columna, siendo el final de esta un **div**

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

una forma mas practica de agregar informacion, simplemente con me metodo attr agregas la clase en la columna que deseas. buscando dentro de los find('td').eq('columna que deseas implementar la clase o evento').

```
 var counter = 0;

$('#addRow').click(function () {
    var curren = t.row.add([
        '',
        'x',
        '<input name="ceRol.listaVista[' + counter + '].descripcionLarga" type="text" value="' + counter + '" hidden />' + '<label>' + counter + '</label>',
        "<div style='text-align: center;'> <button type='button' class='add icon-detalle'>add</button> <button type='button' class='delete  icon-detalle'>del</button> </div>"
    ]).draw(false).node();

    $(curren).find('td').eq(0).attr({ 'class': 'details-control' });

    counter++;
});
```